# what if I decommission one of datanode in the cluster which only has two datanodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I setup a hdfs cluster, which has one master(namenode) and two slaves(datanode)

and the dfs.replication is set to be "2"

so every block will be replicated in the two slaves, and the files in the slaves are all the same.

my question is, if I want to decommission one of the two slaves, it always shows "Decommission In Progress", but there is no files being copied(by use sar to moniter the network)

So I think if the cluster only have two datanodes, and the replication is set to be "2", I can not decommission any datanode, because if I decommission any of the node, there will be only one node left, so the file can not be replicated 2.

Do you think so?

Comment: What does your experiment show? We have  data nodes with a replication count of 2 and set the following property "dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable" to "false" to not have jobs fail in case of node failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe with replication factor of 2 in a cluster, if you decommissioned one data node then hadoop will identify as a crash of one data node and will continue working with data node. However in future if you ever put that node back in cluster hadoop will start replicating files to that node.

So you can have replication factor of 2 with only one node in cluster, it will not hamper working of hadoop in any way.

Comment: I think after submitting the job if i decommissioned a node then it will work as u are saying.  But after completion of these jobs, if new jobs are submitted then it may give errors during submission saying "there is only one datanode and replication factor is 2"(somewhat like this) ...?  Correct me if i am wrong...